# How to add a scroll bar to a drop down list in alfresco share form?

Tags: alfresco, freemarker, alfresco-share

I have a dropdown list in a share form which has about 20 times. The dropdown list uses the alfresco selectmany.ftl. How can I customize the selectmany.ftl to have a scroll bar? Is there any other alternative way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to customize the **selectmany.ftl**, and create your custom control.Add your css customization in it.You will be able to achieve it using this.

You can refer below link for same as reference.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/forms-custom-formcontrol.html